# Gruntfile Jade task compiling weird template

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, gruntjs, pug

I have a pretty simple jade template with a single variable. However, when I generate the html file, a bunch of jade javascript is pushed in and a runtime.js file is created.

Here is my task:

```
jade: {
    prod: {
        options: {
            data  : {
                mainJs: 'dist/main.js',
            },
            pretty: true,
            extension: ".html"
        },
        files:[{
            src: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.jade',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
        }]
    }
}
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the grunt-contrib-jade plugin? If so, please check the format of the "data" and "files" options.

Based on the examples on the [plugin page](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jade), here's what I think you could do:

**"data" option**

```
data: function () {
    return require('./dist/main.json');
}
```

Note that the required file would need to be a JSON rather than JS file.

**"files" option**

```
files: {
    '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html': '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.jade'
}
```

Lastly, I see no "extension" option in the documentation.